# Initialize Values of 2D Array using Nested For Loops

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am trying to format an array that is the following:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
[11] [12] [13] [14] [15]
```

How could I initialize the two dimensional array and the values using nested for loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of two dimensional arrays. Think of them beeing arrays containing arrays.

if you really want this:

```
[[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
[11] [12] [13] [14] [15]]
```

You could initialize it like that:

```
int[][] array2d = new int[15][1]
for (int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++) {
    array2d[i][0] = i + 1;
}
```

If in fatc, what you really want is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

you could use:

```
int[][] array2d = new int[3][5]
for (int i = 0; i < array2d.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2d[0].length; j++) {
        array2d[i][j] = (i * array2d[0].length) + j + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could use a third variable, like `k`, for better understanding of the Original Poster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how I could then print the array in the order of the columns? Such as: 1 6 11 2 7 12 3 8 13 etc...

Comment: @user2057847: Yes, I know. That's a new question. Try something, if you can't figure it out, post a new question containing what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
int width = 5;
int height = 3;
int[][] array = new int[height][width];

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = i + j + (width * i);
    }
}
```