# Java Q. How can I do insert&delete&print in Two Dimensional Array

Tags: java

Java Q. How can I do insert & delete & print in Two Dimensional Array...

How I can do it in 
Two Dimensional
like this
    `private int [] [] arr = new int [3] [3];`

If I do it in 1D array like this

```
public class List {


    private int [] arr=new int[1000];
    private int size=0;


    public void add(int e){
        arr[size]=e;
        size++;

    }

    public void dispaly(){
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" "); 

        System.out.println();
    }

    public void insert(int e,int pos){
        if (pos<=size){
        size++;
        for(int i=size;i>pos;i--)
            arr[i]=arr[i-1];

        arr[pos]=e;
        }
        else System.out.print("unbounded ..");      
    }



    public void delete(int e){

        int pos=locate(e);
        if (pos!=-1){
          for(int i=pos;i<size-1;i++)
              arr[i]=arr[i+1];

          size--;
        }

    }


+++++++++++++++++++++++


                List list=new List();
        list.add(10);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(40);

        list.delete(103);

        list.dispaly();
```

Comment: [Initialize Values of 2D Array using Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14841851/669576)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested "for" loops to print the array. The first for handling the row number, and the second handling the column number.

Comment: You can use the same iteration technique to handle the other two methods as well.

Comment: ok what about add insert some value to the array if it like this
1   7   0
2   8   3
4   9   2


and i want to add colum to be 

1   7   0   1
2   8   3   2
4   9   2   2

it is example

Comment: I want to add method like this but deffrent to be 2d 


public void insert(int e,int pos){
    if (pos<=size){
    size++;
    for(int i=size;i>pos;i--)
        arr[i]=arr[i-1];

    arr[pos]=e;
    }
    else System.out.print("unbounded ..");      
}